# How can I do a replication and only modify certain data in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, replication

I have to do a replication of an entire database, with all its tables, the difference is that only tuples that meet a conditional should be replicated. I just want to modify and replicate the data of the tuples that col1 has the data one. I do not know how to do this part with the replication tool that MariaDB has by default, or I do not know if I have to do it with an external tool.

For example, I have the following table:

```
col1 | col2 |

   1 |    2 |

   3 |    7 |

   6 |    5 |

   3 |    4 |

   4 |    1 |
```

Only the data that has 1 in col1 is replicated

Thank you.

Comment: You are definitely misunderstanding replication. You can instead create a new table, and use triggers to populate it conditionally

Comment: I do not understand what you say, the trigger I implement it in the master or slave server ???

Comment: Replication will ensure one-to-one match between databases in Master and Slave. You need to create a separate table (in Master); it will automatically get replicated in Slave server. Triggers on Master table will similarly get auto replicated to Slave

Comment: Please explain your desire for this partial replication; there may be a better solution.